# How do I fully include the Batik library in my Java project?

Tags: java, svg, jar, buildpath, batik

I am trying to add the Batik library to my Java project. I added the unzipped binary to my lib folder, and added all of the JARs in the top level to the build path.

[image]

[image]

However, when I make the following `import` statement:

`import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;` I get the following error:

"The import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory cannot be resolved"

Other import statements do not exhibit this problem, such as the following:

`import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;`

As far as I understand, the `SAXSVGDocumentFactory` class exist somewhere in the binary I added to the lib folder, so the issue must be with adding JARs to the build path. How can I make sure that all of the Batik source files are added to the build path correctly and are usable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be resolved because it doesn't present in 1.8 jar. It exists in 1.7.
http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SAXSVGDocumentFactory.html

The easy way to find this out is to find the right jar and click to open it by the package: org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory. You wont see this class in 1.8 jar, but you will see it in 1.7 jar.

To fix, download a 1.7 jar and add it to your project again.
http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/xmlgraphics/batik/source/

Answer (score 2):

If somebody can't find SAXSVGDocumentFactory after updating Batik in legacy project, just change the import:

```
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
```

with

```
import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
```